# NameError: undefined local variable or method for #<Class in Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror, activesupport-concern

I am trying to sanitize attributes that come in as a string. I have set up a module with multiple methods that the model will call on `validate`.

Class:

```
class Preset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Shared::AttributeDataSanitizer
  class AttributeError < StandardError ; end

  validate :attribute_sanitization

  def attribute_sanitization
    raise AttributeError if sanitize_attributes(string).errors.length > 0
  rescue AttributeError
    errors.add(:string, "errored, some of your attributes are just terrible.")
    false
  end

end
```

Module:

```
  module Shared::AttributeDataSanitizer
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def sanitize_attributes(string)
      errors = []
      text = string.dup
      extract(text).each do |attr|
        if attr.validation != "valid"
          errors << result
      end
    end

    def extract(text)
      calculation.scan(/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/)
    end
  end
end
```

When `extract` is called inside `sanitize_attributes` the following error occurs:

```
[Rollbar] Reporting exception: undefined method `extract' for #<Preset:0x007f7dce91ba60>
```

[Rollbar] Exception not reported because Rollbar is disabled

NoMethodError (undefined method `extract' for #<Preset:0x007f7dce91ba60>):
  app/models/concerns/shared/attribute_sanitizer.rb:8:in`sanitize_data_attributes'
  app/models/preset.rb:27:in `attribute_sanitization'
  app/controllers/presets_controller.rb:25:in`block in update'
  app/controllers/presets_controller.rb:24:in `update'

`extract` is not a private method, but is this raising an error because it thinks it's a class method? Should this be an instance method? 
Note: More than one class needs to use this.